# Error con group by en mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo la siguiente `query`:

```
SELECT count(id_estadistica) AS num_clicks, a.*, b.* FROM estadisticas AS a LEFT JOIN noticias AS b ON a.id_elemento = b.id_noticia 
WHERE b.id_noticia IS NOT NULL AND b.fecha_pub BETWEEN '2017-10-01 00:00:01' AND '2017-10-31 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY a.id_elemento 
ORDER BY num_clicks 
DESC LIMIT 0, 20;
```

El problema es que al ejecutarla, `mysql` me devuelve este error:

> #1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'a.id_estadistica' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Antes tenia la versión 5.5 de mysql y me funcionaba bien. 
El problema es que mi proveedor de servidor no me da la opción de volver atras en la versión.

Y tampoco puedo ejecutar `querys` del tipo:

```
set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Porque me sale este error:

> #1227 - Acceso negado. Usted necesita el privilegio SUPER para esta operación

¿Existe alguna forma de poder solucionarlo sin cambiar la versiónn de mysql?

Comment: habría que conocer la estructura de `estadisticas` y `noticias` para saber qué campos contiene en realidad la salida teórica y entender qué debiese tener tu group by.

Answer (score 1):

Esa consulta no ha podido funcionarte nunca.
Cuando utilizas la cláusula `GROUP BY` todos los campos de la `SELECT` deben aparecer en la cláusula `GROUP BY` o estar dentro de una función de agregado (como `COUNT`)

Si ejecutas la consulta:

```
SELECT count(id_estadistica) AS num_clicks, a.id_elemento
FROM estadisticas AS a 
LEFT JOIN noticias AS b ON a.id_elemento = b.id_noticia 
WHERE b.id_noticia IS NOT NULL AND b.fecha_pub BETWEEN '2017-10-01 00:00:01' AND '2017-10-31 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY a.id_elemento 
ORDER BY num_clicks
```

sí debería funcionarte. Si quieres añadir más campos en el resultado de la `SELECT` deberás añadirlos también en la cláusula `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Si digo que me ha funcionado será por algo. Antes me funcionaba. Gracias por tu respuesta, ahora lo compruebo

Comment: *Cuando utilizas la cláusula GROUP BY todos los campos de la SELECT deben aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY o estar dentro de una función de agregado (como COUNT)*, eso no es para nada cierto. En el `SELECT` puede haber perfectamente columnas que no estén en el `GROUP BY`. [Aquí un ejemplo](http://rextester.com/MEXTU3854). Te voté negativamente por afirmar algo tan desorientador.

Comment: Tienes razón. Aunque es cierto para otras bases de datos en el caso de MySQL sí que las permite. Sin embargo no se considera una buena práctica, de hecho la configuración por defecto de MySQL a partir de la versión 5.7.5 creo que tampoco las permite.